# How to update Java Jframe controls from no-gui class on real time

Tags: java, swing, asynchronous, model-view-controller, jframe

I have a tedious problem with my Java JFrame project.

What I want to do (and looking for how to) is add elements to my `ListBox` from a no-GUI class in REAL TIME, or in other words "asynchronous", with out freezing my app. Is this clear? I tried `SwingWorker` and Threads but without results. All I can do is update the listbox after all process finish (obviously with my app froze because my process is long).

This is my architecture:

[image: Project Architecture]

And here is my code (not functional, just for understanding)

**EDITTED**

**View (Generated with NetBeans)**

```
package view;

import com.everis.ingesta.controller.MyController;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyView extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MyView(DefaultListModel<String> model) {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnRun = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jscrlLog = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jlstLog = new javax.swing.JList();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnRun.setText("Run");

        jscrlLog.setViewportView(jlstLog);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(159, 159, 159)
                .addComponent(btnRun)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jscrlLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(btnRun)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jscrlLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void addButtonListener(ActionListener listener) {
        btnRun.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyController();
            }
        });


    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRun;
    private javax.swing.JList jlstLog;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jscrlLog;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Controller**

```
package controller;

import business.MyBusiness;
import util.MyLog;
import view.MyView;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyController {

    MyLog log;
    MyBusiness business;
    MyView view;

    public MyController(){
        log = new MyLog();
        business = new MyBusiness(log.getLog());
        view = new MyView(log.getLog());
    }

    public void runProcess() {
        view.addButtonListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                business.runProcess();
            }}
        );
    }
}
```

**Business**

```
package business;

import MyLog;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MyBusiness {

    private int counter = 0;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private MyLog log;

    public MyBusiness(DefaultListModel<String> model) {
        this.model = model;a
    }

    public void runProcess() {
        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    publish("log message number " + counter++);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                // this is called on the Swing event thread
                for (String text : chunks) {
                    model.addElement("");
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

}
```

**Log (model)**

```
package util;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class MyLog {

    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    public MyLog() {
        model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    }

    public DefaultListModel<String> getLog(){
        return model;
    }

}
```

Comment: `"I tried SwingWorker and Threads..."` -- and that in fact ***is*** the correct solution.   `"... but without results. All I can do is update the listbox after all process finish"` -- which means that you're doing something wrong, that you've got a bug in your code, likely you're code does not respect Swing threading rules appropriately. The **best** way for us to fully understand your problem is if we could *reproduce* your problem, with a valid [mcve] code post, one including your SwingWorker attempt.

Comment: I've edited your tags -- better to use the more specific [tag:swing] tag that would catch Swing experts than the overly broad [tag:user-interface] tag.

Comment: So the only answer that I can give you at this time is -- yes, use a SwingWorker as you mentioned, and strive to make all the long-running calls in its `doInBackground` method, and **none** of your Swing calls from this method (or code called from this method). That **will** solve your issue. If you need a more specific solution, please read the [mcve] link as noted above.

Comment: Do you want the logs to be added to a `JList` ?

Comment: If so, if you're trying to do what @c0der is asking above, then you probably need to use SwingWorker's publish/process method pair, to update your list's model. **Again**, it would help immensely to see your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that includes your SwingWorker implementation.

Comment: @c0der yes, to  JList

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you mean that I have to do my doInBackground on my bussiness class? I requiere doInBackground on my logger class, because I have another classes using logger

Comment: @WesleyRomero: I'm not saying any such specific thing since we really don't have a full handle on what is happening where. Again, please improve your question. I'm not sure how I can ask this in such a way so that you will take it to heart. You're forcing us to guess, and this is leading to bad answers and frustration. Please help us help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thinking about it...you are right...I should do that on my lng process class, but I have a lot....how can i do a Reusable DoInBackground classs?

Comment: No, SwingWorkers, like any thread, are use once only, although that code can continue to run.

Comment: Ok Iam going to update my question with a verificable example. Dont let me alone

Comment: `" I requiere doInBackground on my logger class, because I have another classes using logger"` -- I'm not sure that I understand why you're doing this, since logging is usually done by pushing data to the logger, something that happens quickly and does not require a background thread. Even if the worker thread were necessary, applications are free to use multiple and varied worker threads.

Comment: Just updated my question (view part). @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm noob in java, just want to do reusable it, because as I said logger is called from a othres class too...

Comment: I hope y edit helps, but it doesnt implements SwingWorker...Maybe u can reproduce it and help me with that

Comment: The view unfortunately is not what matters here. It's how you're implementing the worker -- please show us the important things. Also please read the [mcve] link since your code is not one of these. The code should be small but not the entire program. Rather a small self-sufficient compilable and runnable program that reproduces the problem. A Thread.sleep can reproduce long-running code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an over-simplified example of a long-process generating `String` values that update GUI using a `SwingWorker`.

It is over simplified in an attempt to make the basic use of  a `SwingWorker` somewhat easier to follow.

This is a one-file [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), meaning you can copy-paste the entire code into one file (MyView.java) and execute :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

//gui only, unaware of logic 
public class MyView extends JFrame {

    private JList<String> loglist;
    private JButton log;

    public MyView(DefaultListModel<String> model) {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        log = new JButton("Start Process");
        add(log, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        loglist = new JList<>(model);
        loglist.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));

        add(loglist, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void addButtonListener(ActionListener listener) {
        log.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyController();
    }
}

//represents the data (and some times logic) used by GUI
class Model {

    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    Model() {

        model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        model.addElement("No logs yet");
    }

    DefaultListModel<String> getModel(){
        return model;
    }
}

//"wires" the GUI, model and business process 
class MyController {

    MyController(){
        Model model = new Model();
        MyBusiness business = new MyBusiness(model.getModel());
        MyView view = new MyView(model.getModel());
        view .addButtonListener(e -> business.start());
    }
}

//represents long process that needs to update GUI
class MyBusiness extends SwingWorker<Void, String>{

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_LOGS = 9;
    private int counter = 0;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    public MyBusiness(DefaultListModel<String> model) {
        this.model= model;
    }

    @Override  //simulate long process 
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LOGS; i++) {

            //Successive calls to publish are coalesced into a java.util.List, 
            //which is by process.
            publish("log message number " + counter++);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> logsList) {
        //process the list received from publish
        for(String element : logsList) {
            model.addElement(element);
        }
    }

    void start() { 
        model.clear(); //clear initial model content 
        super.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: As good an answer as we can provide given the question so far. 1+

Comment: The idea is that the OP get's some basics from the answer, and than goes to the more [detailed and advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764365/3992939) staff (0:

Comment: Sorry for delay, I was busy....

Trying to reproduce I get this error:
`lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7`
on 
`view.addButtonListener(e -> bussines.start());`

Im using java 1.7, another way?

Comment: Yes. Replace with `view .addButtonListener(new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    bussines.start();
   }
  });`

Comment: @c0der ok, I have tried to reproduce your solution but when windows app starts it looks empty and short (like size 0,0).. Maybe there is a problem with NetBeans autogenerated code.

Comment: I have updated the question with code modified with your proposal solution

Comment: Ok no problem, on my way

Answer (score 1):

First a few rules and suggestions:

- Your model or here your "business" code should have no knowledge of the GUI, and should not depend on the GUI structure
- Again all Swing code should be called on the event thread, and all long-running code within a background thread
- If you have long running code that changes state, and if this state needs to be reflected in the GUI, this means that you'll need a call-back mechanism of some sort, some way for the model to notify important parties that its state has changed. This can be done using PropertyChangeListeners, or by injecting some type of callback method into the model.
- Make the view dumb. It gets input from user and notifies the controller, and it is updated by the controller. Almost all program "brains" resides within the controller and the model. Exceptions -- some input verification is often done in the view.
- Don't ignore basic Java OOPs rules -- Hide information by keeping fields private, and allowing outside classes to update state only through public methods that you fully control.
- The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) structure is a good one to learn and use, even if not asking a question here. Learn to simplify your code and to isolate your problem in order to best solve it.

For example this code can be copied and pasted into a single file within the IDE of choice and then run:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mcve1 {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // create your model/view/controller and hook them together
        MyBusiness1 model = new MyBusiness1();
        MyView1 myView = new MyView1();
        new MyController1(model, myView);  // the "hooking" occurs here

        // create and start the GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(myView);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start GUI on Swing thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyView1 extends JPanel {
    private MyController1 controller;
    private DefaultListModel<String> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> logList = new JList<>(logListModel);

    public MyView1() {
        logList.setFocusable(false);
        logList.setPrototypeCellValue("abcdefghijklabcdefghijklabcdefghijklabcdefghijkl");
        logList.setVisibleRowCount(15);
        add(new JScrollPane(logList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));

        // my view's buttons just notify the controller that they've been pushed
        // that's it
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Do stuff") {
            {
                putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_D);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (controller != null) {
                    controller.doStuff(); // notification done here
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    public void setController(MyController1 controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    // public method to allow controller to update state
    public void updateList(String newValue) {
        logListModel.addElement(newValue);
    }
}
```

```
class MyController1 {
    private MyBusiness1 myBusiness;
    private MyView1 myView;

    // hook up concerns
    public MyController1(MyBusiness1 myBusiness, MyView1 myView) {
        this.myBusiness = myBusiness;
        this.myView = myView;
        myView.setController(this);
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // long running code called within the worker's doInBackground method
        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // pass a call-back method into the method
                // so that this worker is notified of changes
                myBusiness.longRunningCode(new Consumer<String>() {                    
                    // call back code
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String text) {
                        publish(text); // publish to the process method
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                // this is called on the Swing event thread
                for (String text : chunks) {
                    myView.updateList(text);
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();

    }

}
```

```
class MyBusiness1 {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private String text;

    public void longRunningCode(Consumer<String> consumer) throws InterruptedException {
        consumer.accept("Starting");
        // mimic long-running code
        int sleepTime = 500 + random.nextInt(2 * 3000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
        consumer.accept("This is message for initial process");

        // ...
        // Doing another long process and then print log
        // ...
        sleepTime = 500 + random.nextInt(2 * 3000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
        consumer.accept("This is not complete. Review");

        // ...
        // Doing another long process and then print log
        // ...
        sleepTime = 500 + random.nextInt(2 * 3000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
        consumer.accept("Ok this works. Have fun");
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

---

---

Another way to do the same thing is to use a Swing-compliant PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class Mcve2 {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyBusiness2 myBusiness = new MyBusiness2();
        MyView2 myView = new MyView2();
        new MyController2(myBusiness, myView);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(myView);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyView2 extends JPanel {
    private MyController2 controller;
    private DefaultListModel<String> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> logList = new JList<>(logListModel);

    public MyView2() {
        logList.setFocusable(false);
        logList.setPrototypeCellValue("abcdefghijklabcdefghijklabcdefghijklabcdefghijkl");
        logList.setVisibleRowCount(15);
        add(new JScrollPane(logList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Do stuff") {
            {
                putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_D);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (controller != null) {
                    controller.doStuff();
                }
            }
        }));
    }
    public void setController(MyController2 controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    public void updateList(String newValue) {
        logListModel.addElement(newValue);
    }
}
```

```
class MyController2 {

    private MyBusiness2 myBusiness;
    private MyView2 myView;

    public MyController2(MyBusiness2 myBusiness, MyView2 myView) {
        this.myBusiness = myBusiness;
        this.myView = myView;
        myView.setController(this);

        myBusiness.addPropertyChangeListener(MyBusiness2.TEXT, new TextListener());
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                myBusiness.longRunningCode();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) .start();
    }

    private class TextListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String newValue = (String) evt.getNewValue();
            myView.updateList(newValue);
        }
    }

}
```

```
class MyBusiness2 {
    public static final String TEXT = "text";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private Random random = new Random();
    private String text;

    public void longRunningCode() throws InterruptedException {
        setText("Starting");
        // mimic long-running code
        int sleepTime = 500 + random.nextInt(2 * 3000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
        setText("This is message for initial process");

        // ...
        // Doing another long process and then print log
        // ...
        sleepTime = 500 + random.nextInt(2 * 3000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
        setText("This is not complete. Review");

        // ...
        // Doing another long process and then print log
        // ...
        sleepTime = 500 + random.nextInt(2 * 3000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
        setText("Ok this works. Have fun");
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        String oldValue = this.text;
        String newValue = text;
        this.text = text;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(TEXT, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }
}
```