# How to update Java Jframe controls from no-gui class using SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, asynchronous, model-view-controller, jframe

I've asked this question but need more details.

[How to update Java Jframe controls from no-gui class on real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762220/how-to-update-java-jframe-controls-from-no-gui-class-on-real-time)

The answer proposed coulnd't be tested because when the windows app starts it looks like size 0,0 and when I maximize there is no controls painted.

Anyway, this is my original problem:

> What I want to do (and looking for how to) is add elements to my
>   `ListBox` from a no-GUI class in REAL TIME, or in other words
>   "asynchronous", with out freezing my app. Is this clear? I tried
>   `SwingWorker` and Threads but without results. All I can do is update
>   the listbox after all process finish (obviously with my app froze
>   because my process is long).
>
> This is my architecture:
>
> - Project
> - __Controller
> - __Business
> - __Util
> - __View

And here is my code (trying to reproduce solution proposed)

**View (Generated with NetBeans)**

```
package view;

import MyController;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyView extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static MyController controller;

    public MyView(DefaultListModel<String> model) {

        initComponents();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnRun = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jscrlLog = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jlstLog = new javax.swing.JList();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnRun.setText("Run");
        btnRun.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnRunActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jscrlLog.setViewportView(jlstLog);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(159, 159, 159)
                .addComponent(btnRun)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jscrlLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(btnRun)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jscrlLog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnRunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        controller.runProcess();
    }                                      

    public void addButtonListener(ActionListener listener) {
        btnRun.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                controller = new MyController();
            }
        });


    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRun;
    private javax.swing.JList jlstLog;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jscrlLog;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Business**

```
package business;

import MyLog;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MyBusiness {

    private int counter = 0;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private MyLog log;

    public MyBusiness(DefaultListModel<String> model) {
        this.model = model;a
    }

    public void runProcess() {
        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    publish("log message number " + counter++);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                // this is called on the Swing event thread
                for (String text : chunks) {
                    model.addElement("");
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

}
```

**Log (model)**

```
package util;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class MyLog {

    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    public MyLog() {
        model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    }

    public DefaultListModel<String> getLog(){
        return model;
    }

}
```

Comment: `initComponents()` is never invoked.

Comment: Important side notes: constuctor argument  `DefaultListModel<String> model` is never used. Also read carefully about [mcve]. There is no need to post such a long code just to demonstrate components that are not painted.   preparing mcve not only makes helping much easier, it is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem.

Comment: @c0der I Updated my view, now it loads ok but no working when pressing button...I dont understand what u mean with `DefaultListModel<String> model` is never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues that prevent logs from appearing in the `JList`:

a. model is never used. Too use it add a `model` field :

```
private DefaultListModel<String> model;

public MyView(DefaultListModel<String> model) {
    this.model = model;
    initComponents();
}
```

and assign the model to the `JList`:

```
//change  jlstLog = new JList<>();  to  
jlstLog = new JList<>(model);
```

b. this method

```
public void runProcess() {

    view.addButtonListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            business.runProcess();
        }}
    );
}
```

is never invoked so the button has no action listener.
The full code with this issues cleared can be seen [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/sq3zZAn5Av).

Some additional comments about asking 
The original question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52782963/3992939).
Changing the question after it has been answered is not good practice I believe.
It makes the answers to the question irrelevant, and the work put into them not helpful for future readers. 
Please stick to the "one question per post" policy.
 
Also it has been emphasized a few times in comments to the and previous question the importance of mcve. mcve should demonstrate the **problem**, and **not** your application.

Answer (score 1):

> when the windows app starts it looks like size 0,0 and when I maximize there is no controls painted.

```
public MyView(DefaultListModel<String> model) {
    setVisible(true);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
```

All I see is that you make the frame visible. I don't see where you ever add components to the frame. That is where do you ever invoke initComponents()?

Component need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. And you need to pack() the frame before it is made visible.

Comment: Ok,  I got this, my app runs but not execute when pressing button...Any idea ?

Comment: @WesleyRomero, So your original question has been answered. Glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved. If you have additional problems, then you should ask a separate question. You should include a proper [mcve] with the question, not just a core dump of your code like you did here. You need to learn to simplify the problem. We have no idea what "does not execute when pressing a button" means. So simplify the code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @camickr: he's been asked for MCVE previously on his last similar question, MCVE's *were provided to him as well*.